# Where to put images in cordova app ios platform to be available in themable browser plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have been trying to use native images in following plugin:

https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser

In case of Android it works by placing images in drawable resource, but in case of iOS there seems to be no place where images can be put before building with ionic build.